# defined validation error message are not showing in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean

I am a MEAN learner.

I have write a Schema and save it in Controller class.
In the schema i define validation error message like this way

```
var userSchema = new Schema( {
      name: {type: String, required : 'please insert name'}
  });
User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
User : User
};
```

save it in controller class and print err

```
insertUser.save(function (err,user){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
    else res.send("inserted user name : " + user.name);
});
```

But i find error message

```
{"message":"Validation failed","name":"ValidationError","errors":{"name":    {"message":"Validator \"required\" failed for path name with value `undefined`","name":"ValidatorError","path":"name","type":"required"}}}
```

what change make me achieve to display proper validation message ??

Comment: Are you using any validation package? Need more code to analyze

Comment: Can you define _"display proper validation message"_? It's unclear to whom you want to show what, exactly.

Comment: YES i do. here is the package validate = require('mongoose-validator')

Answer (score 0):

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
   name: { type: String }
});

userSchema.path('name').validate(function (value) {

  return value.length !== 0;

}, 'please insert name');
```